# How do I use the extension functions for BigDecimal in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, bigdecimal

As I understand it, Kotlin has operator overloading for BigDecimal instances.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/

Why can't I actually use it in my program ? Is there some special import I need to do to get this working ? I couldn't understand why it chose to round up to 0.2.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal

fun main() {
    val num = BigDecimal("15.5")
    val den = BigDecimal("100")
    
    val operatorDivide = num/den
    println("Operators- 15.5/100 is: $operatorDivide") // 0.2
    
    val fnDivide = num.divide(den)
    println("Functions- 15.5/100 is: $fnDivide") // 0.155
    
    val fnDiv = num.div(den)
    println("Operator fun ? 15.5/100 is: $fnDiv") // 0.2
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/TB_wmF95N

Comment: Your code runs without error for me, even in the playground link you provided. Please clarify the problem.

Comment: Note if your issue the different results, then keep in mind that `num / den` is equivalent to doing `num.divide(den, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`, not `num.divide(den)`.

Comment: Does the doc of the `div` function help? "The scale of the result is the same as the scale of this (divident), and for rounding the RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN rounding mode is used."

Comment: Yeah, that comes down to the same thing I guess :P

Comment: Yes my issue was the different result. I couldn't understand why it chose to round up to 0.2.

Comment: Note that, in general, it's a bad idea to use `num.divide(den)` because BigDecimal tries to be exact but quite often the result of a division cannot be represented exactly as a decimal number (consider, for example 15.5/300). When dividing BigDecimals, you should generally always specify a `MathContext` or a scale and rounding mode, unless you are absolutely sure the result can be represented as a decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` (aka `/`) is [implemented](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/0938b46726b9c6938df309098316ce741815bb55/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/util/BigDecimals.kt#L40) as

```
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.div(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal = 
    this.divide(other, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
```

This calls [`divide(BigDecimal,RoundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,int)), which does something different from the [`divide(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)) overload that you are calling in your code.

`divide(BigDecimal,RoundingMode)` keeps the scale of `this`:

> Returns a `BigDecimal` whose value is `(this / divisor)`, and whose scale is `this.scale()`.

but `divide(BigDecimal)` only specifies what the *preferred scale* is.

> Returns a `BigDecimal` whose value is `(this / divisor)`, and whose preferred scale is `(this.scale() - divisor.scale())`

The preferred scale doesn't have to be strictly followed by division - at the top of the JavaDocs page, just below the table showing the preferred scales for each operation, it says:

> These scales are the ones used by the methods which return exact arithmetic results; except that an exact divide may have to use a larger scale since the exact result may have more digits. For example, 1/32 is 0.03125.

The "scale" of a `BigDecimal` created using [`BigDecimal(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) constructor is basically "how many decimal places it has" - `15.5` has scale 1, and `100` has scale 0.

`div` maintains the scale of the result as `1`, so the result is rounded to 0.2. 0.155 would need a scale of at least 3 to represent. `divide(BigDecimal)` sets the *preferred* scale to 1, too, but since the exact result can be represented with a scale of 3, the result of `divide` has scale 3.